# Static noise when electric guitar plugged into amp

Tags: static, guitar-amplifier

I have an Epiphone Wilshire that is producing a "static" sounding noise when plugged into an amp. I removed the cover plate and found a loose, black wire (ground?). It looks like the wire is connected to the back of one of the tone knobs.

I suspect a grounding issue, but I'm not familiar enough with guitar wiring to know where this wire should connect.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7flbW.jpg

Answer (score 2):

It is a common ground to all pots and jack.

[image]

Comment: Pre-solder wire, wrap to terminal then reflow solder with a bit more.  Then make sure the wire does not interfere with the plug inserted !!